# How can you add a macos framework as a dependency of a C++ library in Bazel

Tags: c++, macos, qt, frameworks, bazel

I'm working on getting a Qt application building using Bazel on macos in preparation to getting it running cross platform on Mac and Windows.

I started with the linux example of this from github (https://github.com/bbreslauer/qt-bazel-example) and that mostly worked except that the Bazel couldn't link the frameworks from Qt as "cc_library"s. Unfortunately, after changing these to "objc_framework"s both the cc_library and qt_cc_library rules complain that objc_framework types are unexpected:

> "objc_framework rule '@qt//:qt_widgets' is misplaced here (expected cc_library, objc_library, cc_proto_library or cc_import)"

From reading around, I understand that you can have a library depend on a framework (and you'd have to in order to build anything using frameworks) so the question is how can I tell Bazel to do it?

Note: I am using the latest bazelbuild/apple_rules extensions in my workspace setup.